# Where to store the user info in a Windows 8 app?

Tags: xaml, authentication, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm creating a Windows 8 app.  I have a login screen and when I press a button it will authenticate against a REST API. But what do I do when the user is authenticated? Where is the "session"? How can I store who the user is? So far my search has taken me to these answers

**1. ApplicationData.Current namespace**
Where would I store session specific data? Local application data? Temporary application data?

**2. Password Vault**
I've seen this suggested to a similar question, but as far as I understand this is just a password store? How would it help me to keep the current user in session? Or would I simply for a every view I load question the Password Vault:

> This is the users Windows Live ID, what id does he have in my app?

**3. CookieContainer**

Is it possible to store the user info in a cookie when doing a Windows 8 app?

It seems to me a rather simple question to which I hope there is a simple answer :)

Comment: are you storing across sessions or during a single session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an app too  with an authentication against an REST service with a simple OAuth authentication and I store the credentials (AccesstToken and AccessToken secret) in the PasswordVault. One of the advantages (apart from being stored securely) it's synchronized between Windows 8 devices. In the PasswordVault you store the username and the Password in a PasswordCredential

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordcredential.aspx

Comment: This seems to be the recommended approach from what I can find from others posts as well and I think this will work out well for us. I hope :)

Comment: Where are you storing oauth keys and secret if its a javascript app?

Comment: @Jithin you have the same API in JavaScript : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1

Comment: @Matthieu But then, this needs to be done as part of app installation since this is application data. But still the question of how to provide oauth keys and secret securely to the app remains.

Comment: @Jithin, no the question was how to store them, not how to provide them (it's the OAuth provider to provide those tokens). What do you mean by "at installation time"? The user is going to authenticate after, at the first time the app is launched?